# android how to [dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I compile android project through `"ant debug"`.(http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)**

```
...
-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
[gettarget] API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
```

> I found the annotations.jar under ${sdk}\tools\support and trace the
>   build.xml under ${sdk}\tools\ant\build.xml hereunder

```
<echo level="info">Resolving Dependencies for ${ant.project.name}...</echo>
        <dependency
                libraryFolderPathOut="project.library.folder.path"
                libraryPackagesOut="project.library.packages"
                libraryManifestFilePathOut="project.library.manifest.file.path"
                libraryResFolderPathOut="project.library.res.folder.path"
                libraryBinAidlFolderPathOut="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
                libraryRFilePathOut="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                libraryNativeFolderPathOut="project.library.native.folder.path"
                jarLibraryPathOut="project.all.jars.path"
                targetApi="${project.target.apilevel}"
                verbose="${verbose}" />
```

HOW TO ADD annotation.jar TO THE CLASSPATH?
PS:I have added `annontation.jar` under `D:\myproj\android\MyFirstApp\libs`,But still report that message.

Answer (score 0):

In  your Android manifest xml 
change the minimum SDK Version it requires API Level 15

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
 />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
/>
```

Because the dependecy is API level 15

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yesterday, I had changed the target=android-10 in project.properties to 17 and changed the minSdkVersion=17

It was SUCCESSFUL.

But how wl it be ok under android-10?(I want to make it run under 2.3.3)